# Add a button to the last cell of a table view

Tags: ios

I have added two prototype cells to my table view named `FeedItem` and `ButtonItem`. And my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` looks like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    if(indexPath.row != [feeds count] - 1)
    {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FeedItem"];

        FeedItem *item = [feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [self configureTextForCell:cell withFeedItem:item];
        [self configureCheckmarkForCell:cell withFeedItem:item];
    }
    else
    {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ButtonItem"];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

But my app crashes with this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
```

Can someone point what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Post code where you assign data source for UITableView. Probably you are not doing it or you assigned wrong class.

Comment: Sounds like to me it's hitting your else statement, but getting a cell with the name `ButtonItem` is returning nil. If you remove your else statement does it work?

Comment: Doesn't work if I remove the else part. But it works if don't use the if(indexPath.row != [feeds count] part

Comment: Ah, just saw that I had a typo inside ReuseIdentifier. Finally got it to work